# Морфологический разбор слова "Сонный"

Tags: морфология

Качественные прилагательные могут обозначать физические свойства человека, имеют степени сравнения и полную/краткую форму. На сайте Морфология.ру (морфологический разбор дается по словарю Зализника) у этого слова есть краткая форма,м степени сравнения.

Меня интересует в первом значении - это качественное или относительное? Т.е. надо указать качественное/относительное прилагательное, без переходных случаев.
Напр.: золотой: пост. призн. относительное. Но: золотые руки - качественное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сонные видения -происходящие во сне -относительное

Разбудил сонных детей -сонные - спящие, находящиеся во сне - относительное

Вышла сонная женщина (переносное "заспанная, вялая, медлительная")-качественное, т.к. синонимы качественные, можно образовать наречие на -О-сонно кивала.
Сонная лощина, сонное озеро - находящееся в покое - переносное значение, качественное.

У Есенина:

Улыбнулись сонные березки,

Растрепали шелковые косы.

Это развёрнутая метафора, где относительное прилагательное «сонные» переходит в качественное.

Такое часто случается с прилагательными, производными от существительных, когда происходит переосмысление  значения, ослабление связи с производящим существительным(оловянный солдатик > оловянные глаза, каменный столб > каменное сердце, мраморный памятник > мраморное чело, свинцовые пули > свинцовые тучи).

Сонные берёзки - находящиеся в покое, вялые, ленивые,медлительные.(длинный синонимический ряд характерен для качественных прилагательных). Прилагатѳльноѳ начинает приобретать новые грамматические особенности, характерные для собственно качественных прилагательных, - к нему можно подставить наречие степени очень или почти: очень сонные, почти сонные, от него можно образовать наречие на -О : сонно покачивались,можно подобрать антонимы - бодрый, оживлённый, активный.Сравнительной простой степени нет, но аналитическая  возможна: Она была более сонная, чем когда-либо. Превосходная: А самая сонная была та, которая... Зализняка у меня нет, онлайн-словарю не очень доверяю, там есть и краткая форма - сонен, сонна, сонно, сонны. В поэтической речи, видимо, возможно: сонны волны качали шлюпку. Но слишком вычурно. Далеко не всегда имеются ВСЕ признаки качественных прилагательных, но если есть хотя бы 2, уже можно отнести к этому разряду.
Так что в одних значениях относительное, в других - качественное.

В терминах, конечно, относительное - сонная артерия, сонная болезнь.

Comment: @ Людмила, то, что "сонный" может употребляться как качественное и как относительное, это понятно. Но вопрос в другом: как быть быть с подобными словами вне контекста? Напр.: выписать слова с относительными и качественными прилагательными. Куда вписать слово ***сонный***?

Comment: И еще: в учебнике написано: "...нет степеней сравнения у относительных или притяжательных прилагательных в качественном значении". А здесь, получается, есть.

Comment: Ср.: золотой браслет (относительное прилагательное) – золотой характер (качественное значение); лисий хвост (притяжательное прилагательное) – у этого человека лисий характер / лисья улыбка (качественное значение).

Comment: Если вне контекста, то берётся  прямое значение: сонный - относящийся ко сну - относительное, так как смысл слова определяется через существительное сон.

Answer (score 2):

В толковом словаре дается несколько значений прилагательного "сонный", из них к слову "сон" **относятся** слова в первом значении.

СОННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. **к Сон (1 зн.)**. В сонном состоянии. С-ая одурь. **С-ые артерии** (парные артерии по обеим сторонам шеи). С-ая болезнь (инфекционное заболевание, вызываемое укусом мухи цеце и сопровождающееся сильной сонливостью). 2. Погружённый в сон; спящий.  3. Не совсем проснувшийся или хотящий спать. 4. Разг. Вызывающий сон; снотворный.

Вероятно, **физиологическое состояние сна считается качественным состоянием**. Сонная артерия ― **относительное прилагательное**. И еще есть **метафоры**: тихий, сонный пруд, ночные сонные улицы (тоже, разумеется, качественные прилагательные).

Comment: Но в интернете в большинстве случаев указывается, что это качественное.

Comment: Но ведь к первому значению даются примеры: С. пруд, С., застывший воздух.

Comment: Я изменила ответ с  учетом замечаний.

Comment: Sibylla, у Ушакова так объясняется: ***1. прил. к сон в 1 знач. В сонном состоянии. Сонные грезы*** Эти примеры нельзя считать относительными. Но "сонная артерия"  - да, относительное, да.

Comment: Я думаю, что практически всегда это только качественные прилагательные (сонную артерию учитывать не будем). Наверное, это логично: люди бывают спящие, сонные. бодрые, вялые и т.д. В преносном значении это относится к природе,  к окружающей среде.

Comment: Подождем другие ответы.